# Can't get data from database since I linked my tables (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, database, select

Since I created a link between my table Users and Comments, I can't do a select query to get my Users.
When I try to, I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZonderFacebook/loggedIn.php on line 144
>   No users yet!

my main page:

```
include_once('classes/User.class.php');
$user = new User();
$showUser = $user->getUser();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Bugz</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body{
padding-left: 50px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;

div.bugform{
    float:left;
}
div.comments{
    float:right;
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to Bugz</h1>
<div id="getUser">  
    <?php
        if(mysqli_num_rows($showUser) > 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($showUser)) 
            {
                echo "<option value=" . $row['user_id'] . ">" . $row['username'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "No users yet!";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Function in User.class.php

```
public function getUser()
{
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","****","****","PhpProject");
    if ($conn -> connect_errno) {
        throw new Exception("No connection with database!");

    } else {
        $sqlUsertype = "select user_id, username from User;";
        $result = $conn -> query($sqlUsertype);
        return $result;
    }
```

When I put an SQL query in PHPAdmin:

```
SELECT `user_id`,`username` FROM `Users`
```

it gives me the user_id and the username from the users.

Can somebody help me? It's a school project and I'm stuck because of this problem.

Comment: You are missing an `s` in your selecting method. 'Users` not `User`, as per your working example.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for your time. I also found another mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries you posted are not the same

```
SELECT `user_id`,`username` FROM `Users`

select user_id, username from User
```

Maybe change it to Users in the script instead of User

Comment: Thank you, found another mistake ^-^
After 2 days of PHP, can't see my mistakes anymore even if I put on my 'element inspect' on Chrome.
Thanks for your time.